# AMP-carousel arrows not showing on IE and Safari

Tags: css, amp-html

I am implementing AMP-carousel on one of my pages. I intend to use an amp page for both mobile and desktop because my site is relatively simple and I don't need to have two different versions.

The problem is AMP-carousel is not working well on IE and Safari.  Take a look at the official example here https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-carousel/ When you see it with IE or Safari the arrows that control the slider dont appear after the first image, which makes me think this is an "official" bug.

I am using this example in my page:

```
<amp-carousel width="400"
      height="300"
      layout="responsive"
      type="slides">
    <amp-img src="/img/image1.jpg"
        width="400"
        height="300"
        layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="/img/image2.jpg"
        width="400"
        height="300"
        layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="/img/image3.jpg"
        width="400"
        height="300"
        layout="responsive"></amp-img>
  </amp-carousel>
```

Is there a way to fix this issue in IE and Safari?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find any work around? Here is my page: http://stage.goodsportcelebrates.com/photos/movember/

Comment: No I haven't. The only thing I can think of doing is replacing the slider with another pure CSS slider that should work with AMP.

Comment: You both still not got any solution for it? If yes, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `controls` attribute

> **controls** (*optional*) : Displays left and right arrows for the user to navigate carousel items on mobile devices. The visibility of arrows can also be controlled via styling, and a media query can be used to only display arrows at certain screen widths. On desktop, arrows are always displayed unless only a single child is present.

**Code :**

```
<amp-carousel controls width="400"
      height="300"
      layout="responsive"
      type="slides">
    <amp-img src="/img/image1.jpg"
        width="400"
        height="300"
        layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="/img/image2.jpg"
        width="400"
        height="300"
        layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="/img/image3.jpg"
        width="400"
        height="300"
        layout="responsive"></amp-img>
  </amp-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your arrows are disappearing, then you need to add `controls` attribute to amp-carousal.

```
<amp-carousel height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides" controls>
.
.
</amp-carousel>
```